# SceneData error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, ios9

In Xcode 7 GM with Swift 2, I'm getting the error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" on the following line: `var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!`.

Can anyone help me out with fixing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With swift 2 things change a little when loading a .sks file, you should create a fresh new SpriteKit project so that you can see how it works now, basically you do not have to extend `SKNode`, and instead of using the method:

```
var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
```

You do something like:

```
if let scene =  GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") { //your code here i.e. present your scene }
```

Hope that helps!